# Как правильно удалять елементы из NSMutableSet при прохождении по нему?

Tags: objective-c

Я не разрабатываю под Mac, но возникла необходимость поправить баг в Obj-C коде.
Есть `NSMutableSet` элементов, по которым нужно пройтись и при выполнении определённых условий удалить елемент, сократив этот set. В С++ это делается проходом итераторами по контейнеру в стиле `if (remove) it = container.erase(); else ++it;`. Как выглядит аналог этого на Objective-C для `NSMutableSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это несколькими способами. Для примера возьмем Set со строками:

```
NSMutableSet<NSString *> *someSet = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
```

И первый способ – пройтись по нему, удаляя ненужные объекты:

```
[[someSet copy] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull element, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"2"] || [element isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
        [someSet removeObject:element];
    }
}];
// И, по сути, его вариация:
for (NSString* element in [someSet copy]) {
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"2"] || [element isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
        [someSet removeObject:element];
    }
}
```

Другой, более предпочтительный способ – сформировать Set из ненужных объектов и вычесть его:

```
[someSet minusSet:[NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@"2", @"4", nil]];
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что проходить придётся в любом случае по копии исходного сэта?

Comment: @Iceman, если проходиться по исходному и модифицировать его, то получите crash примерно с таким содержанием: `was mutated while enumerated`.